# Why doesn't Java allow creating integers inside a conditional statement

Tags: java

When I try the below code, it gives me an error

```
int a =1,b=2;
if(a < b)
 int c = 10;
```

But if I do the same adding curly braces, it works fine

```
int a =1,b=2;
if(a < b)
{
 int c = 10;
}
```

But I'm just curious as to why Java does not allow creating a variable inside an if-condition.

Answer (score 5):

It's nothing about integers, it's just that you cannot have a declaration under an `if` statement without brackets. Note that it would be totally pointless since it would mean the declaration would be local to the `if` statement, which would also have a single instruction (it's the meaning of no brackets), which means this declaration would never be used.

To make it more "visual":

```
if (condition) instruction;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (condition) {
    instruction;
}
```

so in your case

```
if(a < b) {
   int c = 10;
}
```

is a pointless code since `c` will never be used. Therefore, it makes no sense for Java to allow writing

```
if(a < b) int c = 10;
```

An `if` statement with brackets will allow you any content in the block (even no content at all) but if you make a declaration withoutusing the declared variable you'll still get a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Your `int c = 10;` is supposed to be a block local variable. You can only have these inside, well, a block (or some control structures like `for`), and these blocks are denoted by curlies. A naked `int c = 10;` is not a block.

Comment: @Dici: thanks for the edit. My iPad has no backticks and I could not use my development computer. <g> Now I can use it again.

Comment: Backticks on an iPad - press and hold the single quote character

Comment: @JimGarrison: Thanks! You made my life a little easier. `it works!`. Still a little bit of a hassle on a German keyboard, but possible. Yay!

Comment: You can also use the `{}` button in the editor. If you have a "span"-looking thing hilighted (not a block of lines) it will wrap it in backticks; if you press it with nothing hilighted it inserts a pair of backticks and puts the cursor between them.  For a selected block of lines it indents 4 spaces.

Comment: I have problems highlighting with my ham fingers. <g> otherwise I would use that. I didn't know about the empty " span". Another useful tip! Thanks again.

Comment: Since we're talking about keyboards and hassle, I should say that my fu**ing laptop keyboard is partially not working. I can't type `=` or `}` directly (among other less critical keys), I must copy-paste them from somewhere. Also, the arrows don't work anymore so I have to use the numpad instead. That was the story of a man who cannot program on his laptop anymore. Thanks for reading :D

Comment: @Dici: I would type a "LOL!", but that would be too short for a comment. <g>